# use ajax variables on same html page

Tags: php, ajax, html, jquery

I have used an Input type="date" field for accepting date value from the user in my application. But I have to post value of date named as "sdate" into the address used in the action method as shown below. I want to post value of Input type date field into action of Form Post method.

I have stored those values via AJAX into variables but How to use those AJAX variables into the action of

My written view code is as below:

```
<form method="post" id="report" class="live" target="_blank" action="http://wcidevapps.com/salescentral/jm2/troute.php?custnum=<?php echo $KUNNR?>&staffid='+staffid+'&rdate='+sdate+'">

<fieldset><legend>Today's Tasks</legend></fieldset>

<div class="span5 well">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <label class="control-label"><b> For </b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="stech" id="stech"/>
    </div><br/><br/>

    <div class="form-inline">
        <label class="control-label"><b> On </b> </label>
            <input type="date" class="datefield" name="sdate" id="sdate"/>
    </div><br/><br/>

    <button type="submit" name="open" class="btn btn-primary offset4"><i class="icon-file"></i> Open</button>
</div>

</form>



<script type="text/javascript">

var onFilter = function () {
        var obj = {
            sdate: $("#sdate").val(),
            stech: $("#stech").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: root + 'standard_projects/?json',
            data: obj,
            success: function (d) {
            sdate=d.sdate,
            staffid=d.staffid
            }
        });
    }
    $("#sdate").live("change", onFilter);
    $("#stech").live("change",onFilter);
</script>
```

How can I use those AJAX variables ?
sdate & staffid

Comment: are `sdate` & `staffid` defined outside the function?

Comment: no those are not defined outsside of function

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "use" these variables? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: I just want to send the request to some site for some documents for that I need to give verified staffid Which I am getting into AJAX variable staffid after successful server response that I want to post to the address used in the action of Form tag ..

Comment: if they are not defined outside the function ie, local to the function only and you want to use it, then declare it outside your function like a `var sdate, staffid;`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking for something that happens naturally. Since the beginning of time, the values of form fields are appended, as a query string, to the url specified in the form's action. All you have to do is provide a submit button, or order the form to be submitted from javascript with `form.submit()`.

Comment: and then what to do at the time of using it in my action of form tag?

Comment: Is there not any way to use these variables staffid & sdate into this case?

Comment: Think about what you are doing. You want to make ajax request(s) to one web resource, to obtain data so it can be submitted to another web resource. If at all possible, you should limit the number of requests to one - the form action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ajax variable outside ajax. instead of that Declare variable from start of script

Answer (score 0):

Just use it in your success function

```
<form method="post" id="report" class="live" target="_blank" action="http://wcidevapps.com/salescentral/jm2/troute.php?custnum=<?php echo $KUNNR?>&">

//...
var report=$('#report), 
    url=report.attr('action'), 
    useStaff = function(staffid, sdate){
        report.attr('action', url+'staffid='+staffid+'&rdate='+sdate);
        //submit report or so...
    };
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: root + 'standard_projects/?json',
        data: obj,
        success: function (d) {
            useStaff(d.staffid, d.sdate);
        }
    });
```

Comment: But I want to use those staffid & sdate variables in my form tag action having some address ....

Comment: But It is not concatenating the address value ?

Comment: It is `report.attr('action', url+'staffid='+staffid+'&rdate='+sdate);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `document ready handler` and all seems fine. Well use of `live` is deprecated in latest jQuery versions so instead you can use `.on()` handler for it.

and you are missing some `';'`

from jQuery documentation:

> **As of jQuery 1.7**, the **.live()** method is deprecated. Use **.on()** to
>   attach event handlers.

try this and see if helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var onFilter = function () {
        var obj = {
            sdate: $("#sdate").val(),
            stech: $("#stech").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: root + 'standard_projects/?json',
            data: obj,
            success: function (d) {
            sdate=d.sdate; //<--------------missing ';'
            staffid=d.staffid; //<----------missing ';'
            $('form#report').attr("action", "http://wcidevapps.com/salescentral/jm2/troute.php?custnum="+<?php echo $KUNNR?>+"&staffid=" + staffid + '&rdate=' + sdate + '"');
            }
        });
    }; //<----------------------------------missing ';'
    $(function(){
        $(document).on("change", "#sdate", onFilter);
        $(document).on("change", "#stech", onFilter);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want the answer of how to use my staffid & sdate variables of AJAX into same Page in 'action' attribute of <form> ?

Comment: @Rattatolae see the updated line in the code. where we are attaching the variable to the action of the form.

Comment: It returns back to same page address not to the address given in action?

how can It be done for opening that Link address ?

Comment: the address in action isn't used by <form> & it opens same page Address on which it is right now

Comment: you mean your form is not submitting to the action url.

Comment: yes my form is not using the action and It opens itself in other tab

It should open the "link page" in the action of <form>